# positive and negative parts of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I have this question that I found in a demonstration of a  theorem:

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and  $u^+,u^-$ the positive and negative parts of $u$ respectively. Why do we have this equality:

$$\int_\Omega \nabla u(x).\nabla u^-(x)dx=-\int_\Omega \nabla u^-(x).\nabla u^-(x)dx,$$

where $u$ is a function in the sobolev space $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: Have you tried to use $\nabla f^+ \cdot \nabla f^- =\nabla \bigg(\frac{|f|+f}{2}\bigg)\cdot \nabla \bigg(\frac{|f|-f}{2}\bigg)$ to show that $\nabla f^+ \cdot \nabla f^- =0$?

Comment: @ Irddo exactly what i was doing right now :) but why this equality is true ? you are reading my mind :)

Comment: i mean the last one

Comment: I don't know if the second equality is true but I will try something again, @hichamgauss.

Answer (score 0):

If you define $u^-=\max \{-u,0\}$ then by [Section 4.2.2, Th 4][L. C. Evans and R. F. Gariepy, Measure theory and fine properties of functions] you have $\nabla u^-=\chi _{\{u<0\}}\nabla (-u)=(\chi _{\{u<0\}})^2\nabla (-u)$ and the result follows...