# gradient, positive and negative parts of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I have this question:

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and  $u^+,u^-$ the positive and negative parts of $u$ respectively. Why do we have this equality:

$$\int_\Omega \nabla u(x).\nabla u^-(x)dx=-\int_\Omega \nabla u^-(x).\nabla u^-(x)dx,$$

where $u$ is a function in the sobolev space $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: This is equivalent to $\int \nabla u^+\cdot\nabla u^- dx=0$, which seems obvious

Comment: i don t think so that it is obvious , can you give me an idea how to prove that @ user138668

Comment: $\nabla u=\nabla(u^+-u^-)=\nabla u^+-\nabla u^-$, agreed? Then $ \nabla u^+$ and $\nabla u^-$ has non-overlapping support, so that $\nabla u^+\cdot\nabla u^-\equiv0$

Comment: This question is quite similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564941/positive-and-negative-parts-of-a-function.

Answer (score 0):

It is a classical result that we have
$$\nabla (u^+)(x) =
\begin{cases} \nabla u(x) & \text{if } u(x) > 0 \\
0 & \text{if } u(x) \le 0 \end{cases}$$
and
$$\nabla (u^-)(x) =
\begin{cases} -\nabla u(x) & \text{if } u(x) < 0 \\
0 & \text{if } u(x) \ge 0 \end{cases}$$
for almost all $x \in \Omega$. Your result follows.